# Run script on "Safely remove" action in KDE

Tags: kde, usb

I have a Linux box with KDE 3.5.10. I do not plan to upgrade it soon, so please don't answer that. Now, I want to run a script each time I select the "Safely Remove" option on a  mounted USB stick/HDD. The script must run before the filesystem is unmounted.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you need something to happen BEFORE of AFTER you pull the device when having chosen that option?

Comment: @tink Before. I want to run an _rsync_ based script in order to sync the contents of a folder in my PC with a folder in the USB. I tried with UDEV and action=remove with no success...